# Null pointer exception while adding Labels in Frame using array of Labels

Tags: java, awt

I tried using an array of Labels and used a for loop within the constructor to add those Labels into the frame, But it shows me a Null Pointer Exception.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class arraytest extends Frame    {
    Label[] k = null;
    public arraytest()  {
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        Panel p1 = new Panel();
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)   {
            k[i] = new Label("process "+i);
            p1.add(k[i]);
         }
         add(p1);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Frame f1 = new arraytest();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Label[] k = new Label[5]; -> instantiate your Label array before instantiating it's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Label[] k = null;` is null, You have to initialize it like:

```
Label[] k = new Label[5];
```

Comment: Ya. It works with initializing the label. Grattitude.

Comment: Congrats, please don't forget to select it as answer :)